# What is the most efficient way to reset a WordPress site?

Tags: database, workflow

I occasionally want to reset my WordPress installation back to default--both the database and files. What is the most efficient way to do so?

I know there are viable plugins to reset the database. But are there automated methods to reset the files to default as well? Or do I need to simply delete everything and re-upload all the WordPress files?

Comment: You don't need to reset all of the files. You can delete any extra plugin and theme added, and clear the uploads folder.

Comment: @JackJohansson Right.  Well there's also wp-config.php, and possibly .htaccess.  But I guess you're saying I should just delete them manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to *empty* the site of its *content* (*posts*, *comments*, *terms*, and *meta*) then there's a [wp-cli](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/site/empty/) command for that:

```
$ wp site empty
```

Use the the `--uploads` parameter to delete all files in the uploads folder and `--yes` to skip the conformation.

**Warning: Remember to backup before testing!**

See [the wp-cli docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/site/empty/) for more information:

Comment: In this case I'm not looking to empty the site completely.  I'm looking to reset the database to default.  Furthermore, I don't want to delete everything in the uploads folder.  The default Twenty Seventeen theme contains at least one image, which I believe resides in uploads.  I'd like to keep any and all images associated with that theme.  Also, does your solution address wp-config.php or .htaccess?  I was hoping to reset those files to default as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git and a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# check out a revision
git checkout master

# Force-add the wordpress config to the index so it
# isn't removed in the next step (add any other
# .gitignore'd files you want to keep to the end of
# this)
git add -f config/wp-config.php  

# remove any files/directories not in the index
git clean -fdx

# removes files added to index in step 2 from the
# index (but doesn't remove them from the disk)
git reset
```

Comment: Actually, wp-config.php isn't a file I want to keep necessarily.  Rather, I want to reset it to default.  The same for .htaccess.  And I don't want to remove all files in uploads--I'd like to keep any and all associated with the default Twenty Seventeen theme.  I guess with you solution I would have add those files to .gitignore?